# validate not work when use javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

when i use in view

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Выберете" значение="" 

id="DirectionSide" name="DirectionSide"><option value=""></option>
<option value="27b8c509-8f09-4a0d-ae22-048c2611b7ea">По ходу движения </option>
<option value="f40319b8-aa82-4182-bec2-4c9b0ba0146d">Против хода движения</option>
<option value="7436112a-122c-4809-9f6c-c5aefff17d6d">На центр перекрестка</option>
<option value="266ea166-67e8-446b-95b1-288b0b876eed">Вращается</option>
</select>
```

this work
but when i put in with the help of javascript-it do not work
For example

```
$("#InsertPhoto").before("....");
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> when i put in with the help of javascript-it do not work

That's because the `.validate()` method has already been called and the plugin initialized.  (If you're using `unobtrusive-validation` along with ASP, then unobtrusive plugin has already called `.validate()` for you.)  If the `select` did not already exist when `.validate()` was called, then you cannot expect the plugin to know about it.

If you're going to dynamically create any new elements after the page is loaded (and after `.validate()` is called), then you must use [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

```
$("#InsertPhoto").before("...."); // <- your code

$('select[name="DirectionSide"]').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```